# How to make "Turbulence" work properly on particle system?

Tags: particles, force-fields

I'm trying to make an animated grass field.
I have set the particle system and I want to simulate some wind in the scene, but when I move the Turbulence the particles just start spinning around theyr origins...
[image]

I would like them to bend, or at least rotate in a direction that "appears to be wind".
[image]

I saw many youtube videos making it work properly, so I think I'm missing something.

I set a simplify scene for a better understandig:
https://easyupload.io/qh8v16

These are all the steps I followed in the file:

- Set the type of particles to "Hair"
- Rendered as: "object"
- Turn on "object rotation"
- Rotate the paticle object by 90° on the Y global without apply the rotation
- Add a turbulence

Also workaround would be appricieted, thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. This video explains a lot and I will link it as reference.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nokkzNOGiY0

To have the grass reacting nicely to the force fields you have to instance the particles with the "Particle Instance" Modifier.

- Put a Particle System on your Emitter object
- Put a Particle Instance Modifier on your particle object
- In the modifier panel select the Emitter and the Particle System just created and enable "Create Along Path"
- Select your particle object, enter edit mode, rotate it until you reach the right rotation.

Now it moves much more realistic, beside it will impact more on the performance than the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

Give your turbulence a bit more strength, add some noise and you get:

[image]

[image]

Note: i added another cube with particles and volume distribution to show how turbulence "works". I am not sure whether you are aware of that. Maybe you want to use wind with some noise? Might be looking better with grass.